# scroll is not working inside svg foreign object in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

I have div inside svg foreign object, with overflow:auto

- scroll is only working with mouse wheel, can't drag bar
- it works on firefox, but not on chrome/safari
- it works if no transform on svg-g element

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ranr/ncry8Lmx/

Is it a bug in chrome? any way around it?

```
<svg width="1000" height="800">
  <g transform="translate(100,50)">
    <rect x="4" y="4" width="110" height="90" stroke="#666666" fill="#eeeeee" />
    <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="80">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;overflow:auto;">
        <div>aaaaaa</div>
        <div>bbbbbb</div>
        <div>cccccc</div>
        <div>dddddd</div>
        <div>eeeeee</div>
        <div>ffffff</div>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
    <g>
</svg>
```

Comment: also reported item on chromium https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=568614

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a bug of Chrome/Safari. If you try to change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:scroll`, the div has display out of the `foreignObject`.

Comment: it worked, change overflow:overlay to overflow:scroll in my case

Answer (score 0):

That chromium bug is closed, unfortunately, it looks worse. If you open the jsfiddle, that div content is invisible, except you remove `overflow:auto` style.  I tested, it is still invisible if `overflow-y:scroll`. Test in Chrome v62.  Firefox 57 working well.