# The nested in foreignobject svg does not appear

Tags: html, d3.js, svg, nested, scrollable

The nested in foreignobject svg does not appear. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
   

var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

var fObj = svg.append("foreignobject");
fObj
  .attr("x", "10%")
  .attr("y", "10%")
  .attr("width", "80%")
  .attr("height", "80%")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 80 80")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin slice");
  
  var scrollDiv = fObj.append("div");
  scrollDiv
  .style("width", "100%")
  .style("height", "100%")
  .style("overflow", "scroll");
  
  var scrollSvg = scrollDiv
  .append("svg");
  
  scrollSvg
  .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", "500%")
  .attr("height", "500%");
  
  var rectP = scrollSvg
  .append("rect");
  
  rectP
  .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "cyan");
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

  
</svg>
```

I am expecting add the main `svg` -> `foreignobject` -> `div` -> `svg`. And by doing that I am hoping to get a nested scrollable `svg` element. But for some reasons everything starting with `foreignobject` is not displayed. I do not know what to try.

After checking the console I did not find any errors there.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/66/) is a jsfiddle.

Comment: @RobertLongson, no. That did not help out. And as far as I can tell the `svg` does not care about the case in `foreignobject`. For example over [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Jverma/2385cb7794d18c51e3ab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's foreignObject, not foreignobject (SVG is case sensitive).

Also d3 requires html tags to be prefixed by xhtml:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", "0")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "yellow");

var fObj = svg.append("foreignObject");
fObj
  .attr("x", "10%")
  .attr("y", "10%")
  .attr("width", "80%")
  .attr("height", "80%")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 80 80")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin slice");
  
  var scrollDiv = fObj.append("xhtml:div");
  scrollDiv
  .style("width", "100%")
  .style("height", "100%")
  .style("overflow", "scroll");
  
  var scrollSvg = scrollDiv
  .append("svg");
  
  scrollSvg
  .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", "500%")
  .attr("height", "500%");
  
  var rectP = scrollSvg
  .append("rect");
  
  rectP
  .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "cyan");
```

```css
#drawRegion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh!!! Great thank you. The only problem is that it is still impossible to scroll. Do you know how to fix it? Help me, please.

Comment: It is a pity. It seems it is impossible to accomplish what I want. Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206459/scroll-is-not-working-inside-svg-foreign-object-in-chrome).

Comment: Use Firefox which doesn't have Chrome's foreignObject bugs.

Comment: Are there any other ways to make the nested `svg` scrollable?

Comment: Implement it all yourself. Draw the scrollbars, handle mouse clicks on them, translate the content based on the mouse clicks and move the scrollbar grabber etc etc.